# Does an Indian need a single- or multiple-entry Schengen visa for visiting Switzerland, Croatia and then perhaps Italy?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, italy, switzerland, croatia

I am from India, and I plan to visit Europe for a month. I will be starting with Switzerland, and then I plan to go to Croatia.

If I have a single-entry Schengen visa and go to Croatia, will I be allowed to enter back into a Schengen country (maybe Italy) or do I need a multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Croatia is not part of EU yet. But they will soon this year. They exempt visa for anyone who holds Schengen visa in these types. http://www.mvep.hr/MVP.asp?pcpid=1615&dmid=92#pocdrz

```
* residence permits issued by one of the Schengen area members
* uniform visas (C) or
* long-stay visas (D) issued by one of the Schengen area members
```

However, upon arrival (as I have done this last year) you get a stamp from Croatia border that you're inside Croatia and when you enter Schengen country again you get another stamp from Schengen country border. This counts that you're out and in again (I held multiple entries). I guess it's safe to say that you need multiple entries visa. But you should check with the embassy in India.

Comment: Croatia will join EU this year, but not Schengen

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll take a multiple entry Visa, and will check with the embassy too.